# Dual boot Ubuntu / Ubuntu installation, non-UEFI PC. How do I delete one of the GRUBs?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

A non-UEFI computer I use for experimental install purposes only has two Ubuntu installations set up as dual boot. Currently they are 18.04 LTS and 19.04.

Not knowing any better, I installed GRUB with both installations, and now they can get into a "duelling GRUB" situation with the last one to run `grub-install` grabbing control.

How can I delete GRUB from one of the installations?

I am leaning towards re-installing the 19.04 system without GRUB, but would take an easier way if it exists.

Comment: It's a bit time ago for me, if I remember correctly, `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc` is the command you need. Run `grub-install /dev/sdx` from the system you want to keep control over grub, then in the other system run `dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`, this should give you the needed options to install to PBR or not to install an instance of grub.

Comment: Thanks very much for the tip! Will look into it.

Comment: More info on mook765's suggestion. This only works for BIOS installs. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2189643

Comment: Thanks to you as well for the additional information.

Comment: @mook765 Your suggestion solved my problem, if you care to write it as an answer, I will accept it. In any case, my thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First decide which of the both systems should control the grub instance in the MBR.
Boot this system and run

```
 sudo grub-install /dev/sdX
```

to make sure this system now controls grub. In the second step boot the other system and run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
```

During reconfiguration of the package you will have the choice to install an instance of grub to the PBR of the system-partition or not to install an instance of grub at all.

That's all, you're done, only one OS will reinstall an instance of grub to the MBR from now on when a system-upgrade ships with a new version of grub.