# GRUB boot question

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I am running Windows 7, Ubuntu 18.04, Ubuntu 19.04 in a dual *actually three) boot setup.  Why is not important.

I am using an HP pavilion dv7 laptop.

First thing, everything works just fine.

Now my issue is this.  When ever Ubuntu (i.e. 18.04) does a kernel update, you need to reboot.  OK, so I reboot, when I get to the GRUB menu, it does not reflect the addition or change in the kernel version for 18.04.  So I have to boot into the other Ubuntu (i.e. 19,04), run GRUB Customizer, then reboot back into Ubuntu 18.04, then when you get to the GRUB menu, it reflects the change in the kernel).  The reverse order in Ubuntu does the same thing, so it is not a specific issue from 18.04 to 19.04.  It does it both ways.

You area able to boot into either 18.04 or 19.04 without any problem, it just that the update will not show up in the GRUB menu.

Now this is just an irritation for me, not a problem as far as I can see.  But why is it happening, am I doing something wrong?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Off hand from someone who does not know what they are talking about, I would say it has something to do with grub customizer controlling grub.  When you boot the first time after kernel update, does ubuntu use the new kernel(is only grub not show new kernel)?

Comment: I was in a similar situation and deleting GRUB from one of the Ubuntu installations helped me. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168713/dual-boot-ubuntu-ubuntu-installation-non-uefi-pc-how-do-i-delete-one-of-the  Only for non-UEFI systems though.

Comment: I have many installs. First thing I do is turn off os-prober (grub updates are a lot quicker) and add my entries to 40_custom. Entries boot partition using link to most current kernel or configfile. How to: Create a Custom GRUB2 Screen that is Maintenance Free.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen
Use labels and configfile to boot another install
https://askubuntu.com/questions/344125/how-to-add-a-grub2-menu-entry-for-booting-installed-ubuntu-on-a-usb-drive/344359#344359 &
https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Multi_002dboot-manual-config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're doing nothing wrong, that's the way it works.

The boot-loader will read it's configuration-file (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) from the system which installed the boot-loader, this is, following your example 19.04 at the moment. So if you have a new configuration-file in 18.04, the boot-loader will not read that file, it reads the one from 19.04.

You're doing the right thing, you have to boot into 19.04 and update grub's configuration there, that's the hassle with multiple boot systems and there is no way around that.

Sometimes a system-upgrade installs a new version of grub and then also reinstalls the boot-loader. Following your example, at the moment you use the boot-loader from 19.04. You upgrade 18.04 and during the upgrade a new version of grub is installed.
From that moment on you will use the boot-loader from 18.04.

**Remember:**
The system which installed grub most recently is the system from which the boot-loader will read it's configuration-file.

Comment: Instead of rebooting, one can just [`chroot` to update GRUB](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) from the currently running Ubuntu system. (The `grub-install` lines can be skipped in this case.)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that information.  Glad that I understand GRUB better.