# Update-grub links to incorrect partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2

I've got two installations of Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer. Ideally I just want one but when I run `sudo update-grub` it keeps updating the configuration for the wrong partition. I eventually want to delete the second partition but don't want to do so until I can relink my main partition with grub.

```
> sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-28-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-112-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-112-generic
Found Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (18.04) on /dev/nvme0n1p6
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

The partition I want to delete is /dev/nvme0n1p6. And the one I want to keep and link with grub is /dev/nvme0n1p1 but it doesn't seem to be detected. Is there a way to safely change configurations so that it updates grub for /dev/nvme0n1p1? I will eventually delete /dev/nvme0n1p6 if it is save to do so.

Edit:
I tried to the suggested post [askubuntu.com/questions/1168713/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168713/dual-boot-ubuntu-ubuntu-installation-non-uefi-pc-how-do-i-delete-one-of-the) (I know it's for non-UEFI) and got the output below when running on /dev/nvme0n1p6 (partition I want to delete).

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc
[sudo] password for dionode: 
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-28-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-28-generic
Found Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (18.04) on /dev/nvme0n1p1
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Sudo update-grub from this same partition also contains that line `Found Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (18.04) on /dev/nvme0n1p1` so it looks like update-grub from each partition only finds Ubuntu for the other partition. Is that normal?

Comment: What do you mean by pain partition?

Comment: Woops sorry, I've changed it back to main partition (which is the one I want to keep)

Comment: I had the same problem and it was solved here https://askubuntu.com/q/1168713/243321  But comments say that this only applies to non-UEFI systems. Pointing you to that question and answer in case it sheds some light on your UEFI system.

Comment: I applied your suggestion @OrganicMarble and it worked! (despite mine being a UEFI system) Thank you! I'm happy to mark that as answer if you like :)

Comment: @dionode That's great news! I'm glad it fixed your problem.   I guess that means this is a duplicate, but I can't vote to close it.  If you like, give my old question and its answer an upvote though.

Comment: Yup! I'm happy to close it but the question is a bit different and your one looks like it's specifically for non-UEFI systems. Maybe would be better to leave it up in case people don't recognise it as a double grub issue?

Comment: Sounds good to me. Consider writing an answer, it's fine to answer yourself,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with multiple grub installations so one of them was effectively not being used. I managed to save this problem by following the post [askubuntu.com/questions/1168713](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168713/dual-boot-ubuntu-ubuntu-installation-non-uefi-pc-how-do-i-delete-one-of-the) which was directed at non-UEFI systems but turns out to work for UEFI systems too.