# Ubuntu Budgie not in Grub menu anymore

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, ubuntu-budgie

I have two drives on my notebook: a HD with Windows on it and a SSD with Ubuntu Budgie.

Dual boot was working perfectly until I came up with the idea to install Feren OS on the Hard Drive. Since Feren and Budgie are both Ubuntu-based, I reckoned I would end up with the three OS-choices in the Grub menu.

Unfortunately, this was not the case and I have now only two options in my Grub menu: Feren and Windows, which are both on the HD. And Ubuntu Budgie is gone from Grub.

What would be the easiest way to get Budgie back into the grub menu? Do I have to run the installer again, and if so, is there anything else I can mess up during setup?

```
sudo update-grub
```

returns:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/60_feren-theme.cfg'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/feren/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-65-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-65-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-60-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-60-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

Comment: You might want to install Grub Customizer (done with a `sudo apt install grub-customizer`) so that this can be done visually. Add a record and set it to the partition with  Budgie. When you hit save, the `sudo update-grub` command will be run so that you don't have to do it yourself.

Comment: Which of the systems controls the GRUB? (If you don't understand what I'm asking, read this question and its answer https://askubuntu.com/q/1168713/243321) If you boot into that system and run `sudo update-grub`, what is the output?

Comment: In the Grub Customizer, when I try to add the entry for Ubuntu Budgie, I get "Error building boot sequence" whenever I choose the SSD partition /dev/sdb

Comment: @OrganicMarble, kindly see my updated answer. Budgie is on /dev/sdb

Comment: I don't have those files in `grub.d` that are called out - the theme file, and `init-select.cfg`, so I don't know what they do. It looks like `os-prober` is running because it found Windows. So unless there is an issue in those files I don't have, I am out of ideas.